# Having trouble loading a parallel array from text in C++

Tags: c++

sorry if there was a duplicate for this question, I only saw people asking this in C.
I'm trying to load up a parallel array with data from an external data file, but when the file should open and begin loading, all I get in my output is a blank console.

The code in question is...

```
include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
...
Void InventoryData::loadArrays()
{
    ifstream partIn;
    partIn.open("inventoryPricing.dat");
    if (partIn.is_open())
        {
            //Prime Read
            partIn    >>    partNum[invCount]
                      >>    price[invCount];


        while(!partIn.eof())
            {
                invCount++;
                partIn  >>  partNum[invCount]
                        >>  price[invCount];

            } //END While

        partIn.close();
        }   //END IF*/

    else
        {
            invCount = -1;
            cout<<"File failed to open."<<endl;
        }

}
```

When I comment out the if statement, everything is fine and I get the "file failed to open"  statement no problem, but if it tries to open it's just a blank screen? No idea where to begin to look, could a wiser set of eyes steer me on the right path?

**EDIT:** After following some advice, I added a cout line right under each loop. It now returns every file, but also one additional.
On top of that, with this new addition, the file now continues into the other lines of code where it didn't before?

Comment: That's a natural result of the code you show - i.e the only output statement exists in the block to be executed if the file doesn't open.  Rather than looking for output (that isn't generated), why dont you either (a) watch the code running in a debugger, or (b) try printing the data immediately after reading it. I.e `cout << partNum[invCount] << " - " << price[invCount] << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

> It now returns every file, but also one additional.

Your code's testing `eof()` incorrectly.  You should test for the success of the input operation, almost never `eof()` unless you've already had an input failure.  Correct code is:

```
if (ifstream partIn("inventoryPricing.dat"))
{
    invCount = 0;

    while (partIn >> partNum[invCount] >> price[invCount])
        ++invCount;

    if (partIn.fail())
    {
        // could set invCount to -1 to avoid partial processing?
        std::cerr << "File parsing failed after " << invCount << " entries\n";
    }   
}
else
{
    invCount = -1;
    std::cerr << "File failed to open.\n";
}
```

> On top of that, with this new addition, the file now continues into the other lines of code where it didn't before?

I can't even guess what you might mean by that....